# Where do shared memory of non-resident threadblocks go?

Tags: cuda

I am trying to understand how shared memory works, when blocks use alot of it.

So my gpu (RTX 2080 ti) has 48 kb of shared memory per SM, and the same per threadblock. In my example below i have 2 blocks forced on the same SM, each using the full 48 kb of memory. I force both blocks to communicate before finishing, but since they can't run in parallel, this should be a deadlock. The program however does terminate, whether i run 2 blocks or 1000.

Is this because block 1 is paused once it runs into the deadlock, and switched with block 2? If yes, where does the 48 kb of data from block 1 go while block 2 is active? Is it stored in global memory?

**Kernel:**

```
__global__ void testKernel(uint8_t* globalmem_message_buffer, int n) {
    const uint32_t size = 48000;
    __shared__ uint8_t data[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        data[i] = 1;

    globalmem_message_buffer[blockIdx.x] = 1;
    while (globalmem_message_buffer[(blockIdx.x + 1) % n] == 0) {}
    printf("ID: %d\n", blockIdx.x);

}
```

**Host code:**

```
    int n = 2; // Still works with n=1000
    cudaStream_t astream;
    cudaStreamCreate(&astream);
    uint8_t* globalmem_message_buffer;
    cudaMallocManaged(&globalmem_message_buffer, sizeof(uint8_t) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) globalmem_message_buffer[i] = 0;
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    testKernel << <n, 1, 0, astream >> > (globalmem_message_buffer, n);
```

*Edit: Changed "threadIdx" to "blockIdx"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my gpu (RTX 2080 ti) has 48 kb of shared memory per SM, and the same per threadblock. In my example below i have 2 blocks forced on the same SM, each using the full 48 kb of memory.

That wouldn't happen.  The general premise here is flawed.  The GPU block scheduler only deposits a block on a SM when there are free resources sufficient to support that block.

An SM with 48KB of shared memory, that already has a block resident on it that uses 48KB of shared memory, will not get any new blocks of that type deposited on it, until the existing/resident block "retires" and releases the resources it is using.

Therefore in the normal CUDA scheduling model, the only way a block can be non-resident is if it has never been scheduled yet on a SM.  In that case, it uses no resources, while it is waiting in the queue.

The exceptions to this would be in the case of CUDA preemption.  This mechanism is not well documented, but would occur for example at the point of a context switch.  In such a case, the entire threadblock state is somehow removed from the SM and stored somewhere else.  However preemption is not applicable in the case where we are analyzing the behavior of a single kernel launch.

You haven't provided a complete code example, however, for the `n=2` case, your claim that these will somehow deposit on the same SM simply isn't true.

For the `n=1000` case, your code only requires that a single location in memory be set to 1:

```
while (globalmem_message_buffer[(threadIdx.x + 1) % n] == 0) {}
```

`threadIdx.x` for your code is always 0, since you are launching threadblocks of only 1 thread:

```
testKernel << <n, 1, 0, astream >> > (globalmem_message_buffer, n);
```

Therefore the index generated here is always 1 (for `n` greater than or equal to 2).  All threadblocks are checking location 1.  Therefore, when the threadblock whose `blockIdx.x` is 1 executes, *all  threadblocks in the grid* will be "unblocked", because they are all testing the same location.  In short, your code may not be doing what you think it is or intended.  Even if you had each threadblock check the location of another threadblock, we can imagine a sequence of threadblock deposits that would satisfy this without requiring all `n` threadblocks to be simultaneously resident, so I don't think that would prove anything either.  (There is no specified order for the block deposit sequence.)

Comment: Sorry, you are ofcourse correct, it should be blockIdx.x not threadIdx.x. Fixed it, and the program still terminates.

I do not agree with you that a sequence exists so this works. Take the case of n=2

What should happen:
  1. Block 0 writes to global_mess[0]
  2. Block 0 waits for Block 1 to write to global_mess[1]
  3. Block 1 is never scheduled because Block 0 is waiting for Block 1 before it exits.
  4. Deadlock.

But somehow this deadlock does not occur, which means both threadblocks are on the SM at the same time?

Comment: That's not the case.  Why would block 1 not be scheduled?  The GPU block scheduler will put block 0 on one SM and block 1 on another SM.  Your GPU has many SMs.  There is nothing in your code that restricts the block scheduler to only using 1 SM.

Comment: I see, i was of the mis-understanding that specifying a stream forces all blocks on the same SM. 
I've rewritten the block-lock into the following, and now it breaks at the 69'th block, precisely as it should. 
Thank you so much, you've been an awesome help!


`while (true) {
    int sum = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (globalmem_message_buffer[i] == 1) 
   sum++;
 }
 if (sum == n)
  break;
}`